# I cannot add an environment variable on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, batch-file

I want to add an environment variable using `setx` command.
I used this syntax.

```
setx /M path "%Path%;C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools"
```

After i enter this, this error happen.

> access to registry path is denied.

How do i fix this error?

Comment: You must be an a Administrator in order to do this

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you! Your answer was helpful. Could you post it as an answer? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You must be an a Administrator in order to do this - [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound)

I post as an answer myself. In order to do add an environment variable, I have to log in as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not enough to be logged in as an administrator, but also the CMD where you run the SETX command must be run as administrator. A workaround would be to start the SETX command through powershell:

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process SETX \"/M myvariable myvalue\" -Verb RunAs"
```